# Issues on error : fd, addr = self._accept()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp

Im trying to make a connection betwen server and client in python. but the program just running till waiting for a connection.The program cannot read the addres.

```
import socket
import sys

host = ''
port = 5131

s = socket.socket()

s.bind((host,port))

s.listen(1)
print('listening')


while 1:

    print('Waiting for a connection......')
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connection established with', addr)


c.close()
```

and the result is like this :

```
listening
Waiting for a connection......
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/muhrisdham/Downloads/tugas/01.tugas_tcp_server.py", line 32, in <module>
    c, addr = s.accept()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 212, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

pardon my english, thank you before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you must have pressed ctrl+C when the program got stuck. Hence the KeyboardInterrupt.

What you've written is the *server*. It's meant to block at the `s.accept()` call until a new connection is made to the address it's listening to (0.0.0.0:5131) in your case. Once a new connection is made you would handle that connection (somehow).

Now all you've got left to do is to implement the *client*.

Check out this tutorial: https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html